# JS Intl.NumberFormat for currency cant have maximumFractionDigits 0

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am using the JavaScript Intl object, and I want to format a number (150 for example) to look like "£150". For Chrome untill the update to version 59 this code worked perfect:

```js
var GBPFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
      style: 'currency',
      currency: 'GBP',
      maximumFractionDigits: 0
  });
```

but now it says that the "maximumFractionDigits" can not be 0, and after reading in https://developer.mozilla.org/ i found that for GBP maximumFractionDigits can not be less than 2.

All well and good, but i still need to have "£150" not "£150.00". Any ideas how i can still use the Intl object and make it look the way i need.

P.S. I know that i can make my own function that dose the same, but considering that i do not have only GBP but a bit more currencyes, I prefer to stick with a ready solution.

Comment: How about formatting the result of the formatter using a wrapper function - removing the fraction digits?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set the `maximumFractionDigits` option to `0` like you want, but the value needs to be higher than `minimumFractionDigits`. Because the default value for `minimumFractionDigits` is higher than `0` for this currency, you'll need to set both of them manually to get what you want:

```js
var GBPFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'GBP',
  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
  maximumFractionDigits: 0
});

console.log(GBPFormatter.format(150)); // Should output "£150"
```